# 'where' clause error in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to postgreSQL. I'm trying to execute some simple queries but i'm having an error i'm stuck with. Following is a simple query

```
select e.street, e.city 
from employee e join works w join managers m on e.Lastname=w.Lastname 
and w.Lastname=m.MLastname
where w.companyname='Union Pacific';
```

The error that is being thrown while executing this query is

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "where"
LINE 4: where w.companyname='Union Pacific';
        ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "where"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 124
```

I couldn't understand this error. Need some help.

Answer (score 3):

Did you mean

```
select e.street, e.city 
from employee e
join works w
join managers m on (e.Lastname=w.Lastname and w.Lastname=m.MLastname)
where w.companyname='Union Pacific';
```

? Probably not. Probably you meant:

```
select e.street, e.city 
from works w
join employee e on w.Lastname=e.Lastname
join managers m on w.Lastname=m.MLastname
where w.companyname='Union Pacific';
```

Answer (score 1):

The join of `works` lacks a join condition. Follow it with `on` or `using`.